# how to set forloop for function in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I was getting values in due to for each it was repeating same values

```
---------------------------------------------- 
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
          var i=0;
  $("#add_row").click(function(){
  $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><select name='job_id"+i+"' class='form-control'><option value=''>Select the Job</option><?php 
            $mysql="select * from ca_job where job_status != 'Closed' and job_customer_name = '".$com_id."'";
            $result1 = mysql_query($mysql) or die(mysql_error());
            while($roww = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
            $sql="select * from `ca_job_type` where `jtype_id`= '".$roww['job_type']."'";
            $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res);
         echo '<option value='.$row1['jtype_id'].' selected>'.$roww['job_id'].'-'.$row1['job_type_name'].'</option>';
          } ?></select></td><td><input name='sac_hsc_code"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='description' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td><td><input id='i"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='SAC/HSC Code'  class='form-control input-md' ></td><td><select id='employee"+i+"' name='tax_id"+i+"' class='form-control'><option value=''>Please select</option><?php
            $sql = "select tax_id, tax_type, tax_comp, tax_Percent FROM ca_taxmaster where tax_comp = '0'";
            $resultset = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($resultset)) { echo '<option value='.$rows['tax_id'].' selected>'.$rows['tax_type'].'</option>'; } ?></select></td><td class='appendData'></td><td><input name='amount"+i+"' type='text' class='form-control amt' id='amount"+i+"' class='form-control input-md' style='text-align: right;' ></td><td><input name='store"+i+"' type='hidden' id='store"+i+"' class='form-control input-md' style='text-align: right;' ></td>"
            );
    $("#employee"+i).change(function() {
     var length = i;       
     var tax_id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
     var dataString = 'tax_id='+ tax_id;
    $.ajax({
    url: '<?=base_url(); ?>ajax/getEmployee.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(employeeData) {
    if(employeeData) {
       var employee = [employeeData];

----------I think I was getting the error because of this forEach ---------------------------


      employeeData.forEach(function(item) {
       var data = '<tr>';
       data+= '<td colspan="4"> </td>';
       data+= '<td align="right">'+item.tax_type+'</td>';
       data+= '<td align="right">'+item.tax_Percent+'</td>';
       data+='</tr>';
     $('.appendData').append(data);
         });
       }
     }
    }); 
    });

  $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');    
  i++;       
   });
  $("#delete_row").click(function(){
   if(i>1){
 $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
   i--;
    }
   });
  });
</script>
```

Same value was repeating in all places. I attached a screenshot for reference. Please help if anybody knows. Thanks in advance

[image: i need output like]

[image: Table for your reference]

Comment: Please check your code, I think you have to use "employeeData.each()'  instead of 'employeeData.forEach()'

Comment: Thank you, Mukesh but I use each()  noting showing

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong the `$("#employee"+i).change(function() {` is not enclosed under `$("#add_row").click(function(){`.
Because if it is enclosed then it might create some issue.
Also for the separation of concern you should write `PHP code` in a separate file instead of calling in `.html()`

Comment: Are your sure your `employeeData` has the right value? What do you get with a `console.log()` ? You have different value or the same one?

Answer (score 0):

try using following way using for loop

```
for(var i = 0 ;i <employeeData.length;i++){
$('.appendData').append('<tr><td colspan="4"></td><td align="right">'+employeeData[i].tax_type+'</td><td align="right">'+employeeData[i].tax_Percent+'</td></tr>')
}
```

Comment: thank you Hussain but not coming same thing repeating in each time

Comment: can you share your response,what you are getting in employeeData?

Comment: you got a typo in append

Comment: ohh yes i have misspelled the apppend its append not appned

Comment: this is my employee data page :<?php include 'db.php';$db=DbConnect(); if($_REQUEST['tax_id']) { $sql = "SELECT tax_id, tax_type, tax_comp, tax_Percent FROM ca_taxmaster WHERE tax_comp='".$_REQUEST['tax_id']."'";
                  $resultset = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                  $data = array();
                  while( $rows = mysql_fetch_array($resultset) ) {
                  $data[] = $rows;
              $rows['tax_comp'] . " " . $rows['tax_Percent'];
                  } echo json_encode($data);} else {echo 0; }?>

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your var `employeeData` has the good value, you can try this maybe :

```
// new empty data value
var data = "";

// you add one row each time you loop
$.each(employeeData, function(item) {
   data += '<tr>';
   data += '<td colspan="4"> </td>';
   data += '<td align="right">'+item.tax_type+'</td>';
   data += '<td align="right">'+item.tax_Percent+'</td>';
   data +='</tr>';
});    

// when it's over, you append your data where you want.
$('.appendData').append(data);

// An other idea could be to create a "container" div and do :
$('#mycontainer').html(data);
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you,  Mickael Leger, I was getting undefined error and loop was repeating same like before clicking this link for your clarification https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TpRA.png

Comment: What do you get when you do a `console.log(employeeData);` ?